# Display image in some certain cells in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridViewImageColumn in datagridview.
I just wanna display image at some rows. But the others display rectangle X.
So how can I hide the rectangle X.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try setting `DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;` for the Image column

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in datagridview1.Rows)
  {
  }
```

Loop after assign Datasource to datagridview1
you can get all row one by one

you can use condition in this loop to set the particular cell style

Answer (score 1):

Change your column `NullValue` to empty bitmap:

```
ColImage.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1);
```

or for every row that is missing `Image`

```
((DataGridViewImageCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]).Value = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1);;
```

It is not very elegant way but it's working. Personally I would create my own empty image and used it for cells missing values :)